# Diskless client nfs boot fails

Tags: ubuntu, pxe-boot, tftp

For a school project I need to create an ubuntu diskless client. I'm using vmware fusion. I've encountered various problems that took me a while to solve, but now I'm at a standstill.

I've been using this guide to help me: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DisklessUbuntuHowto

I arrived at the point it was finally loading something :), but then I got a "connection refused" error as you can see in the image below.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5rZH.png]

this is my dhcp config file
    allow booting;
    allow bootp;

```
subnet 192.168.134.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  range 192.168.134.100 192.168.134.150;
  option broadcast-address 192.168.134.255;
  option routers 192.168.134.1;
  option domain-name-servers 192.168.134.1;

  filename "/pxelinux.0";
}
```

/etc/default/tftpd-hpa file

```
#Defaults for tftpd-hpa
RUN_DAEMON="yes"
OPTIONS="-l -s /tftpboot"


TFTP_USERNAME="tftp"
TFTP_DIRECTORY="/tftpboot"
TFTP_ADDRESS="0.0.0.0:69"
TFTP_OPTIONS="--secure"
```

I've been searching the web for a solution, but was not able to find a working one. I disable the firewall, so that can't be it. I don't have much experience, so it's hard for me to know where to look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `tftp` bit has worked: the kernel is loaded and attempting to mount the root filesystem.  It looks like the NFS server you're trying to mount isn't responding.  Check from another client that you can actually mount `/nfsroot` from your server (assuming you followed the naming convention in the HOWTO).